# How do I place a programatically generated bitmap in a View?

Tags: java, android, view, bitmap, android-relativelayout

I've generated a circle bitmap programatically like so:

```
private Bitmap drawDotCircle() {
        int circleSize = 100;
        circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                circleSize,
                circleSize,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        );

        canvas = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
        CanvasRadius = Math.min(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() / 2);

        // Create a Paint object used to paint the circle
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawCircle(
                canvas.getWidth() / 2,
                canvas.getHeight() / 2,
                CanvasRadius - CanvasPadding,
                paint
        );

        return circleBitmap;
    }
```

I would like to place it at an absolute X and Y that I've calculated; let's assume its the absolute center of the screen as follows:

```
int dotX =getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
int dotY = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 2;
```

How do I ensure that the circle is centered in the view? I have tried the following code, but the circle is always off-center for some reason:

```
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(circleDot.getHeight(), circleDot.getHeight());

// Setting position of our ImageView
        layoutParams.leftMargin = dotX;
        layoutParams.topMargin = dotY;

// Finally Adding the imageView to RelativeLayout and its position
        relativeLayout.addView(dotView, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leftMargin should be dotX - imageWidth/2 and topMargin should be dotY - imageHeight/2

Try that

Comment: This still does not enable the image to be centered. Here is a screenshot of the red dot being positioned using my original x & y calculation: http://i.imgur.com/t8VGB7c.jpg, and then a screenshot of your suggested calculation:http://i.imgur.com/V9X2zdW.jpg In both instances, the dot is off center